# Get only the txt file you want from the folder containing the txt file - Python

Tags: python, pickle

I have a folder with a `.txt` files. the name of the files are:

```
my_file1.txt
my_file2.txt
my_file3.txt
my_file4.txt
```

In this way, only the last number is different.

```
import pickle

my_list = []
with open("/Users/users_a/Desktop/website-basic/sub_domain/sub_domain01.txt", "rb") as f1, 
open("/Users/users_a/Desktop/website-ba\
sic/sub_domain/sub_domain02.txt", "rb") as f2, open("/Users/users_a/Desktop/website- 
basic/sub_domain/sub_domain03.txt", "rb") as f3:
    my_list.append(pickle.load(f1))
    my_list.append(pickle.load(f2))
    my_list.append(pickle.load(f3))

print(my_list)
```

In this way, I load a file and put it in the `my_list` variable to make a list and work. As the number of files to work increases, the code becomes too long and cumbersome.

Is there an easier and more pythonic way to load only the desired `txt` file??

Comment: Are you only using files that are in the form `my_file<number>.txt`?

Comment: Instead of importing all the files in the folder, I want to select and import only the desired txt files.

Comment: Added an alternative for that in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `os.listdir()`:

```
import os
import pickle

my_list = []
path = "/Users/users_a/Desktop/website-basic/sub_domain"

for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        with open(f"{path}/{file}","r") as f:
            my_list.append(pickle.load(f))
```

Where `file` is the filename of a file in `path`

> I suggest using [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) instead of hard coding the file paths

---

If your folder only contains the files you want to load you can just use:

```py
for file in os.listdir(path):
    with open(f"{path}/{file}","r") as f:
        my_list.append(pickle.load(f))
```

---

**Edit** for `my_file[number].txt`

If you only want files in the form of `my_file[number].txt`, use:

```py
import os
import re
import pickle

my_list = []
path = "/Users/users_a/Desktop/website-basic/sub_domain"

for file in os.listdir(path):
    if re.match(r"my_file\d+.txt", file):
        with open(f"{path}/{file}","r") as f:
            my_list.append(pickle.load(f))
```

> Online regex demo https://regex101.com/r/XJb2DF/1

Comment: You need to `pickle.load` a `file object` as stated here [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#:~:text=pickle.load). Your code will pickle the path to the file string.